# jQuery malfunction after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an issue now where I'm using slidetoggle to hide/reveal my main navigation:

```
$("#menu_block_button").click(function(){
    $("nav #block-menu-block-2 > div > div > ul").slideToggle();
})
```

It works fine until I load ajax on the page. It'll perform the toggle twice when after that point. I assume the script is being loaded in again after the ajax.

What can I do to remove the event before triggering it?

Comment: You will need to provide more of your code. Not enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the only listener for that particular element, and it is the AJAX that is the problem, then at the end of your success function of your AJAX request, add this code:

```
$("#menu_block_button").off();    
$("#menu_block_button").click(function(){
  $("nav #block-menu-block-2 > div > div > ul").slideToggle();
})
```

This will remove any event listeners attached to the element and add the one you want back.  HOWEVER, if it is still happening twice, you must have code in there already that adds the event listener, so just add this code in your success function:

```
$("#menu_block_button").off();
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind and unbind handlers can bring trouble. It's much better to use delegate events.

Events are sent bottom-up from the elements in the DOM tree. A delegate event handler is attached to the container of the elements which will trigger the handled event. When the event is triggered, it's not handled in the element itself, but bubbles up until it reaches the container which has to handle it. So the container is the responsible to handle the event. (The container "knows" which element triggered the event, so it can decide if it handles it or not, depending on a selector).

If you choose a container that isn't replaced by AJAX updates, you don't have to worry about binding and unbinding handlers after the ajax updates.

How do you do it? It depends on the jQuery version.

It used to be `.live()` or, preferably `.delegate()`

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/): Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. (Deprecated in 1.7, remove in 1.9)

[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/): Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Now, the recommended way to do it is `on()`:

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/): Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

For using `on()`, you have to do this:

`$('container selector').on('event','triggers selector', 'handler')`

For example, to use the function `clicked` to handler all the links (`a` elements) inside the div with id `navbar`:

`$('div#navbar').on('click', 'a', clicked);`

You can make this call only once, and it will keep working provided the navbar div isn't updated in the AJAX updates. (If this div is updated, choose an outer element which isn't! You can always choose the body, but it's better to handle it as near as possible to the trigger)

NOTE: if you use `event.stopPropagation()` at any point, the event stops bubbling up the DOM tree. If you don't call it, and there are any other delegated events for the same event, the event will be handled again.

NOTE: this is also interesting for handling events that can be triggered by many different elements. For example, if you have a table, with many rows, which have several links in each of them, and want to handle the click on this links, it's better to bind a single handler to the table than to bind the trigger for all this elements.

Answer (score 0):

Binding and unbinding this element is a band-aid.  IMO you should audit your code and refactor it so it does not get executed twice.  Otherwise, you will probably have numerous other adverse effects.  If you post your code, I can probably tell where the trouble is.